# Slick2d Restarting States

Tags: java, slick2d

How do you restart a state in slick2d? When my game ends and when it goes back to the main menu, after I click to play again, it loads the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the enter() method. It is called each time you enter a state.